# EasyTable - Paragraph in a cell

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using your EasyTable library and it is fantastic, for my use it is better than itext7. I have only one problem. I'm trying to insert a paragraph with multiple lines inside a cell but it gives me an error. Here is my class.

The error is:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.vandeseer.easytable.drawing.cell.ParagraphCellDrawer.drawContent(ParagraphCellDrawer.java:52)
        at org.vandeseer.easytable.TableDrawer.lambda$new$0(TableDrawer.java:53)
        at org.vandeseer.easytable.TableDrawer.drawRow(TableDrawer.java:161)
        at org.vandeseer.easytable.TableDrawer.drawWithFunction(TableDrawer.java:145)
        at org.vandeseer.easytable.TableDrawer.lambda$drawPage$1(TableDrawer.java:75)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.vandeseer.easytable.TableDrawer.drawPage(TableDrawer.java:74)
        at org.vandeseer.easytable.TableDrawer.draw(TableDrawer.java:70)
        at it.baz.ProvaPDF.crea(ProvaPDF.java:66)
        at it.baz.ProvaPDF.main(ProvaPDF.java:21)
```

`package it.baz;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.vandeseer.easytable.TableDrawer;
import org.vandeseer.easytable.settings.HorizontalAlignment;
import org.vandeseer.easytable.structure.Row;
import org.vandeseer.easytable.structure.Table;
import org.vandeseer.easytable.structure.cell.TextCell;
import org.vandeseer.easytable.structure.cell.paragraph.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ProvaPDF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProvaPDF pdf = new ProvaPDF();
        pdf.crea();
    }

    private void crea() {
        try {
            PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

            final PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
            document.addPage(page);

            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

            Table myTable = Table.builder()
                    .addColumnsOfWidth(100, 100)
                    .addRow(Row.builder()
                            .add(TextCell.builder().text("One One").borderWidth(1).backgroundColor(Color.GRAY).build())
                            .add(TextCell.builder().text("One Two").borderWidth(1).backgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY).build())
                            .build())
                    .addRow(Row.builder()
                            .add(TextCell.builder().text("Two One").borderWidth(1).textColor(Color.RED).build())
                            .add(TextCell.builder().text("Two Two").borderWidth(1).horizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT).build())
                            .build())
                    .addRow(Row.builder()
                            .add(TextCell.builder().text("Two Two").borderWidth(1).horizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT).build())

                            .add(ParagraphCell.builder()
                                    .paragraph(ParagraphCell.Paragraph.builder()
                                            .append(StyledText.builder().text("This is some text in one font.").build())
                                            .appendNewLine()
                                            .build())
                                    .build())
                            .build())
                    .build();

            TableDrawer tableDrawer = TableDrawer.builder()
                    .contentStream(contentStream)
                    .startX((page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightX() - 200) / 2)
                    .startY(page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY() - 20)
                    .table(myTable)
                    .build();

            System.out.println(page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY());
            System.out.println(page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightX());

            tableDrawer.draw();

            contentStream.close();

            document.save("example.pdf");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}`

Thank you.

Comment: it fails in `drawingContext.getPage().getAnnotations().forEach(PDAnnotation::constructAppearances);`, see https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vandeseer/easytable/drawing/cell/ParagraphCellDrawer.java . Find out whether with your debugger if `drawingContext` is null, or if `drawingContext.getPage()` is null. (`PDPage.getAnnotations()` is never null)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Vandaer suggested this solution:

```
TableDrawer tableDrawer = TableDrawer.builder()
            .contentStream(contentStream)
            .page(page) // <-- This was missing
            .startX((page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightX() - 200) / 2)
            .startY(page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY() - 20)
            .table(myTable)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

The code of Paolo doesn't run for all versions. To help, here is one comination of versions that works:
pom.xml

```
<repositories>  <!-- This is to find <artifactId>pdfbox2-layout</artifactId> -->
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.vandeseer</groupId>
    <artifactId>easytable</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ralfstuckert.pdfbox-layout</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox2-layout</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId> 
      <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId> 
      <version>2.0.22</version> 
    </dependency>
```